# Avahi DNS-SD on multiple IP addresses

Tags: linux, ip, ip-camera, avahi, dns-sd

**Background:**

I'm trying to communicate with an IP camera without the need of a DHCP server. This is how the camera acquires an IP address:

1. Basic DHCP procedure (discover etc.)
2. If above should fail the camera has a fallback address of **192.168.0.90**
3. The camera then starts the avahi-daemon and successfully gets a link-local address too for robustness
4. The IP aliasing is now done and the interface has two IPs.

**Problem:**

Now the problem is that when I *avahi-browse* to browse the services on the network, the camera replies with both IP addresses (checked with Wireshark).

Only one is shown by avahi and it could be the zeroconf:ed address or the fallback address.

**I want the link local address only, not the fallback. Any reliable way to get it?**

Answer (score 2):

Old question but just in case someone else has the same problem:

- Avahi will only return one of the IP addresses reported by the device. This seems to be a (debatable) design decision and is explained [in this post](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/avahi/2009-May/001646.html) of the avahi mailing list. So I'm afraid there's no reliable way to get only the link-local address, if you are using avahi-browse.
- On a side note, [RFC3927 section 1.9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927#section-1.9) specifically recommends NOT to configure both a routable address and a link-local address simultaneously for the same interface. But I do understand this is the camera's behaviour and probably outside your control.

Comment: Yeah, keyword is "Should not" which means that there probably exists reasons for them to have it implemented in that way. 
Either way, it is probably Avahi that should have it supported :/

Comment: I think the RFC uses "should not" here because the result of doing this is *undesirable* ("leads to complexity for applications and confusion for users") but does not *break* anything (functionality, interoperability). But I agree with you in that it would be nice for Avahi to just report all reported IP addresses instead of just one.